# POST Request Work on POSTMAN but not in PHP

Tags: php, craigslist

I need to POST and get content of the reply email.

**Link** - https://sacramento.craigslist.org/cto/d/north-highlands-2005-toyota-tacoma-4x4/7102315098.html
In this link there will be Reply button. When you enter the button an XHR request will send with form data named as `browserinfo3`. Inside they send browser specific data. 
But I have tried the request **without any params** in POSTMAN. Just changed the request type to POST and result has been returned successfully. 
Now I have written the same script in PHP by using Guzzle. Tried many ways but no success. **It always returns 404 request.** Can you please tell me how to POST correctly in order to get successful request.

```
 $emailUrl = 'https://sacramento.craigslist.org/contactinfo/sac/cto/7102315098';
 $connection = new Client(["http_errors" => false]);
 $page = $connection->post($emailUrl);
```

Comment: Please, always show us some code to see what you have done. If nothin else it helps understand the question when it is not 100% clear what you are asling, as in this case

Comment: Craigslist doesn't want you scraping, and has taken measures to block you.

Comment: @Sammitch I know they do. But it works on POSTMAN but not in PHP. My question is what is the difference ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have used params from browser post request. But the body is very long so not added into the question. But if you inspect browser easily can see it. And the whole code is as in question.